# Altering the page title on a /node/add/ page from a custom module

Tags: 6, hooks, features

I have a new content type I am developing that I am packaging using [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features).

What I need to do is alter the page title for the node add page for this content type from the Features' `.module` file. I cannot see an appropriate module hook to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `drupal_set_title()` in `hook_form_alter()`

Answer (score 0):

The node/add/... page is a form, so you could do it with a `hook_form_alter()`.

Comment: I've looked through the array using `dpm()` but I don't see the page title value

Comment: Is it imperative that you do it from a custom module, or would you be willing to use a template? There are a number of tutorials about the latter, such as http://worchestra.com/post/theming-node-forms-drupal-7

Comment: It is to be an agile 'feature' that will be passed around so to speak so, yes, via a module would be the best. p.s. It's a D6 site

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial for doing it via hook_theme() in d6? http://drupal.org/node/310302#comment-1169768 I don't really know what you mean by "agile feature". I don't know how you would go about integrating custom hooks into Features modules.

Comment: Agile as in it can be installed on several sites very easily (by non-devs.) Therefore it cannot utilize `template.php`.
A features' `.module` file can be used just like any other custom module (even if you recreate it, your code will remain intact.)

Comment: Why can't you add a template to your module?

Comment: I've exposed `$form` with `hook_theme()`... still no page title :/

Comment: I am pretty sure that you must include a template file. The good news is that you can do that inside a module, so that it can be installed by non-technical site maintainers.